# How can I get hudson to recognize the PathToWebApp for every project

Tags: c#, asp.net, hudson

I have a hudson server running on my local machine. So far I have only added one project to hudson. I am using svn as my source control. Whenever I build my project on hudson, all the test fail because the %PathToWebApp% variable cannot be recognized by hudson. I can force hudson to recognize the PathToWebApp if I add it as an environment variable in hudson, but then that only works for one project. I need hudson to work for multiple projects.  Btw, I can not use absolute paths for AspNetDevelopmentServerHost any given project will be running on multiple machines. The sample asp.net code is listed below. Its a very basic asp.net test method.

```
[TestMethod()]
[HostType("ASP.NET")]
[AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("%PathToWebApp%\\MyReportingApp", "/MyReportingApp")]
[UrlToTest("http://localhost:51357/")]
public void LoginConstructorTest()
{
     //Login target = new Login();
     //Assert.Inconclusive("TODO: Implement code to verify target");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. Hudson does not recognize the attributes. The settings for the test has to be configured in the Local.testsettings